# What is difference between setHandler/map/composite in Vert.x

Tags: java, kotlin, vert.x

Vert.x has a class called Future (https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Future.html). I`ve already read the doc for setHandler, map and composite in javadoc but I really cannot understand, for me it sounds like as the same thing, could someone which have already had the same doubt help me with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original question and answer mention `setHandler()`, which existed in Vert.x 3, but was removed in Vert.x 4. The `setHandler()` was an alias for `onComplete()`

`compose()` flattens the `Futures` while `map()` doesn't. In Vert.x, `flatMap()` is simply an alias for `compose()`

Use `compose` when the argument of your lambda is a Future. Use `map` when it's a simple object. You should almost always use `compose` in Vert.x, since most methods will return you a Future.

When is it important to flatten values?

Consider the following example:

```java
Future<Future<String>> f = Future.succeededFuture(Future.succeededFuture("a"));
```

Note that the type of `f` is `Future<Future<String>>`

Now let's see what happens when we invoke `compose` and `map` on that `Future`

```java
Future<String> composeResult = f.compose(a -> a);

Future<Future<String>> mapResult = f.map(a -> a);
```

Notice that `compose` stripped one level of nesting, "flattening" the results, while `map` didn't.

The stripping is valuable, since in asynchronous frameworks such as Vert.x, almost all results are deferred values, such as `Future`. By using `compose`, we ensure that the nesting doesn't occur.

Comment: You said : map() unwraps the future but it still returns Future<U>. Therefore im curious, which one is faster between map() vs compose(). In other words, when to choose map(Function<>) over compose(Function<>)? *Thx,

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer was related to Vert.x 3 and is not true anymore, or if it wrong all along. In any case, it needed to be updated.